# Generating overlapping sequences

Tags: python, sequence

I have a dataset with the following information. The `timebin` variable is an identifier for the time period of the data. It can be assumed that `timebin` is unique and without any gaps (i.e. the data will always contain 2 if it contains 1 and 3).

```
timebin,lat,lon
0,9.0,2.0
1,12.0,4.0
2,15.0,6.0
3,18.0,8.0
4,21.0,10.0
5,24.0,12.0
6,27.0,14.0
7,30.0,16.0
```

I want to generate all the sequences of a fixed-length `l` with an amount of overlap `o`. For instance, for `l=4` and `o=2` the following groups of indices would be output:

```
[[0,1,2,3], [2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7]]
```

This could be done using a loop, but I wonder if there is a more elegant and efficient way of doing it in python?

Comment: Why do you stop at 7?

Comment: This was just to keep the example short :)

Comment: OK, I now see that your data ranges from 0 to 7. That's why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
l = 4
o = 2
e = 7

print([[x for x in range(s, s + l)] for s in range(0, e, o) if s + l <= e + 1])
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
overlap = 2
data = [0, 1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5 ,6 ,7]
groups = [data[i: i + overlap * 2]  for i in range(len(data) - overlap * 2 + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the rest of the provided data involved in any way?
Just from your question you could generate those sequences with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = 4
>>> o = 2
>>> [[x for x in range(s, s+l)] for s in range(20)[::(l-o)]]
[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10, 11],
[10, 11, 12, 13], [12, 13, 14, 15], [14, 15, 16, 17], [16, 17, 18, 19],
[18, 19, 20, 21]]
```